# How we can show collection data in array

Tags: arrays

When I am using get api and get the data in json format

```
{
    "uuid": "46d00217-6e35-485c-ac20-c204a8a24a68",
    "name": "AMan",
    "dispute_location": "Hyder",
    "max_dispute_value": "200",
    "min_dispute_value": "100",
    "state": "U.p",
    "district": "morene",
    "calendar_id": "3",
    "description": null,
    "subject_matters": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A",
            "created_at": "2020-08-14T12:24:52.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-14T12:24:52.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "court_uuid": "46d00217-6e35-485c-ac20-c204a8a24a68",
                "subject_matter_id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "created_at": "2020-08-14T12:24:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-14T12:24:57.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "court_uuid": "46d00217-6e35-485c-ac20-c204a8a24a68",
                "subject_matter_id": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but i want subject_matters data in this format

**"subject_matters": [1,2]**

[Api resource (court resources)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUmrC.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Aman! As a good rule of thumb, you should always post what you've done, what the computer did when you told it what to do (like what you wrote above), and what you expected the computer to do (which you also wrote). So what you're missing is to show what you've done to get the above. Else we don't know where to even start helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->pluck('id');` in your resource.

```
return [
  'subject_matters_id' => $this->subjectMatters->pluck('id')
]
```

It should return an array of subject matter IDs.